# Match values to nearest value in another array in R

Tags: arrays, r, match

I need to match a value to its nearest corresponding value in R and extract its index.

The command `FindInterval(value,array)` achieves this but only works if the array is in ascending order.

The command `match(value,array)` only works if the value provides an exact match to one in the array.

For example,

```
array <- c(0.1,0.5,0.6,0.3,0.9,1.4,0.45)
value <- 0.47
```

I'd like a command which then matches this to the nearest corresponding `value` (here 0.45) and returns the `index` (here 7).

Comment: `which.min(abs(array - value))`

Comment: @RonakShah, you sir are what this world doesn't have enough of #hero #notallheroswearcapes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can subtract `value` from every element of `array` , get the absolute difference and get the index position of minimum value using `which.min`.

```
which.min(abs(array - value))
# [1] 7
```